# Proxmox-Server reboots sporadically

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, qemu, lxc, proxmox

I just mentioned that my proxmox-system is rebooting from time to time when performing backup-tasks (bacula, not the proxmox-backup-system).

The logs are showing the following:

```
Mar 8 02:30:01 proxmox-server kernel: [1922972.974633] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400601.487:129743): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=22456 comm="atop" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:30:01 proxmox-server kernel: [1922972.974665] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400601.487:129744): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=22456 comm="atop" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:30:01 proxmox-server kernel: [1922973.110758] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400601.623:129746): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=22532 comm="atop" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:30:01 proxmox-server kernel: [1922973.111619] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400601.627:129747): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=22532 comm="atop" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:31:33 proxmox-server kernel: [1923064.989437] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400693.511:129762): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=11598 comm="monit" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:31:33 proxmox-server kernel: [1923064.989461] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400693.511:129763): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=11598 comm="monit" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:31:34 proxmox-server puppet-agent[31158]: Finished catalog run in 0.63 seconds

Mar 8 02:33:09 proxmox-server kernel: [1923160.542757] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400789.071:129768): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=29153 comm="monit" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:33:09 proxmox-server kernel: [1923160.542962] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400789.071:129769): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=29153 comm="monit" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:34:23 proxmox-server kernel: [1923235.217380] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400863.751:129770): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=31188 comm="monit" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:36:11 proxmox-server kernel: [1923342.872770] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400971.415:129771): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=9471 comm="monit" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:36:13 proxmox-server kernel: [1923344.924216] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400973.463:129772): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=11037 comm="sw-collectd" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:36:13 proxmox-server kernel: [1923344.924251] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400973.463:129773): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=11037 comm="sw-collectd" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:36:28 proxmox-server kernel: [1923360.048495] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400988.591:129777): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=15979 comm="sw-collectd" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:36:30 proxmox-server kernel: [1923361.994794] audit: type=1400 audit(1457400990.536:129778): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=16377 comm="sw-collectd" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:36:49 proxmox-server kernel: [1923380.457157] audit: type=1400 audit(1457401009.000:129784): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=2842 comm="ps" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:36:49 proxmox-server kernel: [1923380.821127] audit: type=1400 audit(1457401009.364:129790): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=2872 comm="ps" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:38:11 proxmox-server kernel: [1923462.649203] audit_printk_skb: 54 callbacks suppressed

Mar 8 02:38:11 proxmox-server kernel: [1923462.649206] audit: type=1400 audit(1457401091.200:129810): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=29153 comm="monit" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:38:11 proxmox-server kernel: [1923462.649433] audit: type=1400 audit(1457401091.200:129811): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="lxc-container-default" pid=29153 comm="monit" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"

Mar 8 02:41:25 proxmox-server rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.4.2" x-pid="920" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start

Mar 8 02:41:25 proxmox-server systemd-modules-load[303]: Module 'fuse' is builtin

Mar 8 02:41:25 proxmox-server systemd-modules-load[303]: Module 'loop' is builtin

Mar 8 02:41:25 proxmox-server systemd-modules-load[303]: Inserted module 'vhost_net'

Mar 8 02:41:25 proxmox-server hdparm[324]: Setting parameters of disc: (none).

Mar 8 02:41:25 proxmox-server keyboard-setup[325]: Setting preliminary keymap...done.

Mar 8 02:41:25 proxmox-server systemd-fsck[482]: /dev/sda3: Journal wird wiederhergestellt

Mar 8 02:41:25 proxmox-server systemd-fsck[482]: /dev/sda3: sauber, 331/62592 Dateien, 64258/250112 Blöcke
```

This is my proxmox-setup:

```
proxmox-ve: 4.1-39 (running kernel: 4.2.8-1-pve)
pve-manager: 4.1-15 (running version: 4.1-15/8cd55b52)
pve-kernel-4.2.6-1-pve: 4.2.6-36
pve-kernel-2.6.32-43-pve: 2.6.32-166
pve-kernel-4.2.8-1-pve: 4.2.8-39
pve-kernel-4.2.2-1-pve: 4.2.2-16
pve-kernel-2.6.32-26-pve: 2.6.32-114
pve-kernel-4.2.3-2-pve: 4.2.3-22
lvm2: 2.02.116-pve2
corosync-pve: 2.3.5-2
libqb0: 1.0-1
pve-cluster: 4.0-33
qemu-server: 4.0-62
pve-firmware: 1.1-7
libpve-common-perl: 4.0-49
libpve-access-control: 4.0-11
libpve-storage-perl: 4.0-42
pve-libspice-server1: 0.12.5-2
vncterm: 1.2-1
pve-qemu-kvm: 2.5-8
pve-container: 1.0-46
pve-firewall: 2.0-18
pve-ha-manager: 1.0-23
ksm-control-daemon: 1.2-1
glusterfs-client: 3.5.2-2+deb8u1
lxc-pve: 1.1.5-7
lxcfs: 2.0.0-pve1
cgmanager: 0.39-pve1
criu: 1.6.0-1
```

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Is it clustered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often when something reboots sporadically, it is not the OS, it is a physical problem.

I'd start with the power supply.  It is a good one, or cheap?  Is there redundant power on the server, or is it a low-end server or desktop.  Is the power overloaded?

It is possible that there are a bunch of disks and those disks all spin and seek when doing backups peaking the power consumption.  This can cause one specific rail (aka voltage bus) of the power supply to become overloaded though the whole PSU is fine.

For example, if the max power on +5V is 20 Amps, and you have 10 disks at 2.1Amps each, then you'll overload the power, and it will shutdown or reboot.